Matching dataframe values to RasterLayer names and performing calculations
In R, I have a list of formal class 'RasterLayer' rasters that I obtained using the following code:
library(raster)
library(terra)
rasterlist <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "*\\.asc", full.names = TRUE, all.files = TRUE)
allrasters.list <- lapply(rasterlist, raster)

The name of each raster in allrasters.list is a unique character name for each individual animal, and is stored in @name in the list.
Examples of the raster file names in rasterlist and allrasters.list look like:
"C:/Folder/Folder/Folder/702778_9109PR_PR.asc"
"C:/Folder/Folder/Folder/702783_9088PR_PR.asc"
"C:/Folder/Folder/Folder/90199_8955PR_PR.asc"
"C:/Folder/Folder/Folder/90732_9094PR_PR.asc"
...

The rasters are continuous values, in a AAIGrid format, floating point, projected raster.
I also have a dataframe of unique Animal IDs and the number of locations for each animal. An example of this dataframe looks like this:
AnimalID    #Locations
90732_9094     5000
702783_9088    7809
90199_8955     4289
90732_9094     8523
  ...          ...

What I would like to do is to first, match the name in the dataframe (i.e., AnimalID) to the name in rasterlist or allrasters.list (whatever makes more sense). Second, multiply the values of that matching raster by the number of locations in the dataframe. And third, write each of those multiplied rasters to a new object (or save them to a new file) so I can further manipulate them.
I've tried the code in this post but I'm not trying to add any values to a dataframe.

How is the partial match? You can use regex to match them. What does the raster represent? BTW, rgdal library is outdated. Consider moving to {terra} as well

@aldo_tapia I have edited my original question to clarify the partial naming match between the raster file and the dataframe information, and to clarify information about the rasters. Which regex function do you recommend for the match and are you thinking a loop between the raster names and dataframe?
